# @reboot via crontab isnt working

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, server, cron

IM running a VPS server on Ubuntu 14.04 minimal x86. I connect to it using putty via SSH.

On the server i have a simple script that is starting a few instances of bots

`nohup node /nodebots/bot10/server.js &`

I use root as a user, so all the privileges and +chmod X are set properly (in my opinion)

The idea is that my node.js program is not excelent + the service im running the bots for sometimes has reboots, server crashes etc.

Ive installed crontab and at this moment struggling to set the script to be run at boot.

Ive used various solutions including trying to boot it via init.d , adding a line to rc.local and well using crontab -e. None of it helps.

Currently the code in crontab looked the following ways

```
`@reboot sh /nodebots/botsrun.sh`
```

`@reboot root /nodebots/sh botsrun.sh`

`@reboot cd /nodebots/ && sh botsrun.sh`

None of it helped.

Im new to Ubuntu, coding and even terminal commands. I would really apreaciate any kind of help. I will be more then grateful for a step by step tutorial on what im doing wrong and what should be done.

Comment: I have the same problem